# What is the meaning of an overline over a finite field?

Tags: finite-fields, information-theory

I'm studying cyclic codes. I read the following theorem :

$\mathbb{F}_q$ is a finite field with q elements. Let's consider $X^n - 1 \in \mathbb{F}_q[X]$.

If $GCD(q,n) = 1 $,

Then  $\exists \alpha \in \overline{\mathbb{F}_q}$ such that $X^n - 1  = \prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(X-\alpha^i)$

But, what is $\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}$ ? I didn't find it anywhere else...

Comment: This the algebraic closure of ${\Bbb F}_q$.

Comment: When we have a polynomial with coefficients in a certain field, for example $x^2 + 2x + 3$ over $\mathbb R$, then this field may not contain all the roots of the polynomial e.g. $x^2+ 1$ has no roots over $\mathbb R$, but has roots in an extension, namely the complex numbers. It can be shown that every field can be extended to an *algebraically closed* field, which contains the roots of every polynomial with coefficients in that field. For example, $X^n - 1$ is a polynomial , so all its roots will be contained in that larger field, which we call  the algebraic closure.

Comment: This algebraic closure is usually denoted by putting a bar over the field variable. Here, it turns out that $X^n -1$ doesn't have all its roots over $\mathbb F_q$, so we must access the algebraic closure of $\mathbb F_q$ to catch hold of these roots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever you read the symbol $\overline{k}$ should be defined somewhere. There are many different types of "closures".

Anyway in the field theory (and it seems to agree with the context of your question) it typically means [the algebraic closure](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_closure) of $k$, i.e. the "smallest" field $L$ containing a copy of $k$ as its subfield and such that every polynomial of positive degree over $L$ has a root in $L$.

These algebraic closures are known to always exist and are unique for $k$.

Note that the algebraic closure of any (finite or not) field is infinite.